# Creating a simple line border around 2 buttons in JSP

Tags: css, jsp

What is the simplest way to create a line box around 2 buttons

```
    <div  align="center" style="max-width:380px; border:2px;">
        <INPUT type="button" value="Find Missing Definitions" onclick="promptUser()">
        <INPUT id="processDefinitionsButton" type="button" value="Process Missing Definitions" onclick="processDefinitions()">  
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Should this not add a line 2px wide ?

Thnx

Comment: what you need is to specify the border style and border color, please refer to w3c document: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<div  align="center" style="max-width:380px; border:2px solid #ccc;">
    <INPUT type="button" value="Find Missing Definitions" onclick="promptUser()">
    <INPUT id="processDefinitionsButton" type="button" value="Process Missing Definitions" onclick="processDefinitions()">  
</div>
```

code for border is like `border: size type color`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the colour and style

```
 <div  align="center" style="max-width:380px; border:2px solid red;">
```